# Pandas DataFrame to JSON with Nested list/dicts

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

Here is my df:

|  | text | date | channel | sentiment | product | segment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | I like the new layout | 2021-08-30T18:15:22Z | Snowflake | predict | Skills | EMEA |

I need to convert this to JSON output that matches the following:

```
[
  {
    "text": "I like the new layout",
    "date": "2021-08-30T18:15:22Z",
    "channel": "Snowflake",
    "sentiment": "predict",
    "fields": [
      {
        "field": "product",
        "value": "Skills"
      },
      {
        "field": "segment",
        "value": "EMEA"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm getting stuck with mapping the keys of the columns to the values in the first dict and mapping the column and row to new keys in the final dict. I've tried various options using `df.groupby` with `.apply()` but am coming up short.

Samples of what I've tried:

```
df.groupby(['text', 'date','channel','sentiment','product','segment']).apply(
     lambda r: r[['27cf2f]].to_dict(orient='records')).unstack('text').apply(lambda s: [
{s.index.name: idx, 'fields': value}
for idx, value in s.items()]
).to_json(orient='records')
```

Any and all help is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe more context or more examples? I don't get it why we need to use `groupby` here. If all you need is to combine some fields of each line into a single `fields` json object, I think we can just do a `df.to_json(orient='records')` and then do the other combining work with just an extra python for loop.

Comment: Hey@Brandon. I was able to get something working. See below. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solved with this:

```
# Specify field column names
fieldcols = ['product','segment']

# Build a dict for each group as a Series named `fields`
res = (df.groupby(['text', 'date','channel','sentiment'])
 .apply(lambda s: [{'field': field, 
                    'value': value}
                   for field in fieldcols
                   for value in s[field].values])
).rename('fields')

# Convert Series to DataFrame and then to_json
res = res.reset_index().to_json(orient='records', date_format='iso')
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "text": "I like the new layout",
    "date": "2021-08-30T18:15:22Z",
    "channel": "Snowflake",
    "sentiment": "predict",
    "fields": [
      {
        "field": "product",
        "value": "Skills"
      },
      {
        "field": "segment",
        "value": "EMEA"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```